# How to set ndk path in Qt Creator for android?

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, qt-creator

I have downloaded the android NDK 23b latest version and unzip it in Ubuntu. I have the set the correct path in Qt Creator but it is still showing the error as shown in the image.

[image: Showing error in android ndk path.]

Answer (score 1):

Qt versions depend on different NDK versions. That's why you cannot directly download any version and expect QT to recognize latest version. [Qt says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-getting-started.html#android-ndk)

[image]

Try to install NDK through Qt options screens.

Comment: I tried that also but still showing the same error.

Comment: Hope you are not showing another ndk path in your user environment right?

Comment: I am not showing any ndk path in user environment right.